Error compiling COBOL program with sequential files
I have this COBOL program in my mainframe:
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                          
       PROGRAM-ID. TEST2.                                                
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                             
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                                             
       FILE-CONTROL.                                                     
           SELECT DATOS ASSIGN TO INPUTFL.                               
       DATA DIVISION.                                                    
       FILE SECTION.                                                     
       FD DATOS.                                                         
          01  REG-DAT.                                                   
              05  ID-LB           PIC 9(10).                             
              05  TITULO          PIC X(16).                             
              05  GEN-1           PIC X(8).                              
              05  GEN-2           PIC X(11).                             
              05  STOCK           PIC 99.                                
              05  FILLER          PIC X(33).                             
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                          
           01  FIN      PIC X VALUE 'N'.                                 
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                               
       1000-ABRIR.                                                       
           OPEN INPUT DATOS                                             
                PERFORM 2000-LEER UNTIL FIN = 'S'                       
           CLOSE DATOS                                                  
           STOP RUN.                                                    
       2000-LEER.                                                       
           READ DATOS                                                   
                AT END MOVE 'S' TO FIN                                  
                NOT AT END PERFORM 2100-MOSTRAR.                                                    
       2100-MOSTRAR.                                                    
           DISPLAY 'ID LIBRO: ' ID-LB.                                  
           DISPLAY 'TITULO: ' TITULO.                                   
           DISPLAY 'GENERO PRINCIPAL: ' GEN-1.                          
           DISPLAY 'GENERO SECUNDARIO: ' GEN-2.                         
           DISPLAY 'STOCK: ' STOCK.                                     
           DISPLAY '--------------------------------'.                             

Before testing it I must compile it but when I run the JCL it pops me a 0012 error.
This is the JCL:
//HERC0101 JOB (COBOL),                                              
//             'COBOL COMPILATION',                                  
//             CLASS=A,                                              
//             MSGCLASS=H,                                           
//             REGION=8M,TIME=1440,                                  
//             NOTIFY=HERC01,                                        
//             MSGLEVEL=(1,1)                                        
//****************************************************************** 
//*                                                                  
//* THIS JOB HAS AS PURPOSE COMPILE THE COBOL CODE                   
//* PROCEDURE LOCATED @ SYS2.PROCLIB(COBOL)                          
//*                                                                  
//****************************************************************** 
//COMPILE  EXEC COBOL,                                               
//         PROG='TEST2',                                             
//         PDSF='MBVT.APPLICBC.SRC',                                 
//         PDSL='MBVT.APPLICBC.LOAD'                                 
/*                                                                   
//                                                                   

I've tried using another and simpler code, like this one:
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.     
       PROGRAM-ID. TEST2.            
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.        
       DATA DIVISION.               
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.          
           DISPLAY 'HOLA MUNDO!!'.  
           STOP RUN.                

And the JCL compiled it correctly, but with the other it showed me this error:
IEF202I HERC0101 LKED COMPILE - STEP WAS NOT RUN BECAUSE OF CONDITION CODES
The log shows all the procedure and after showing the code it shows this:
                                                                                
 6      IKF1155I-W     DEVICE CLASS INVALID IN SYSTEM-NAME. SKIPPING TO NEXT FIE
6      IKF1141I-W     FILE ORGANIZATION FIELD INVALID IN SYSTEM-NAME.  SEQUENTI
6      IKF1157I-E     EXTERNAL-NAME NOT PRESENT IN SYSTEM-NAME.                
6      IKF2133I-W     LABEL RECORDS CLAUSE MISSING. DD CARD OPTION WILL BE TAKE
27     IKF4052I-E     NOT    MAY NOT BE TARGET FIELD FOR ALPHANUMERIC LITERAL  
                      AND IS DISCARDED.                                        
27     IKF4052I-E     AT    MAY NOT BE TARGET FIELD FOR ALPHANUMERIC LITERAL  (
                      AND IS DISCARDED.                                        
27     IKF4052I-E     END    MAY NOT BE TARGET FIELD FOR ALPHANUMERIC LITERAL  
                      AND IS DISCARDED.                                        
28     IKF4072I-W     EXIT FROM PERFORMED PROCEDURE ASSUMED BEFORE PROCEDURE-NA
                                                                                


Almost all COBOL issues can be fixed by adding more periods (. characters) :-)

The system is missing a DD statement for file INPUTFL

where in the JCL should I put the DD statement?

Usually on mainframes, the JCL to compile the COBOL program is separate from the JCL to run the compiled COBOL program.

@Juan, you really shouldn't be asking these questions here.  https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ is the appropriate place, as you're only going to confuse people and yourself.  If you insist on asking them here, you need to start by telling people that you're running on MVS Release 3.8J, so people who are familiar with newer OSes don't try to help you with information that isn't correct on the OS you're using.

@GilbertLeBlanc as I wrote in my post, I'm not trying to run the COBOL program, just compile it

"And the JCL compiled it correctly, but with the other"  What other?  There should be one and only one JCL to compile a COBOL program.

the other code @GilbertLeBlanc read the full statement

NOT AT END was added with COBOL85, so that may not be available on very old emulators.
The compiler then applies these to the MOVE statement with multiple targets as if you have coded
        MOVE 'S' TO FIN
        MOVE 'S' TO NOT
        MOVE 'S' TO AT
        MOVE 'S' TO END

and therefore outputs IKF4052I-E on that line three times
NOT    MAY NOT BE TARGET FIELD FOR ALPHANUMERIC LITERAL AND IS DISCARDED.
AT     MAY NOT BE TARGET FIELD FOR ALPHANUMERIC LITERAL AND IS DISCARDED.
END    MAY NOT BE TARGET FIELD FOR ALPHANUMERIC LITERAL AND IS DISCARDED.

If you really need to use that ancient compiler recode the READ as follows:
           READ DATOS                                                   
                AT END MOVE 'S' TO FIN.                                 
           IF FIN NOT = 'S'                                             
              PERFORM 2100-MOSTRAR.                                     

As Kolusu pointed out, you need a device class "UT" utility device = disk and organization identifier "S" sequential:
       FILE-CONTROL.                                                     
           SELECT DATOS ASSIGN TO UT-S-INPUTFL.                            

To fix the label records warning change the FD to read:
       FD DATOS LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.                              

In any case you should start the level 01 in col 8-11, so move the FIN declaration at least one column left:
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                          
          01  FIN      PIC X VALUE 'N'.                                  

To fix the last warning you may try to add the following:
       2095-LEER-EX.                                                    
           EXIT.                                                        


As mentioned in your previous thread, you are using an old emulator and hence all the weird messages. Just for the record, the program compiles fine on z/OS
You are using  an old (e.g. MVT) COBOL compiler which has totally different syntax compared to the COBOL compiler used on the z/OS machine.
So you can try to change this line
SELECT DATOS ASSIGN TO INPUTFL.     

TO
SELECT DATOS ASSIGN TO UT-S-INPUTFL.

which will get rid off the error message shown on line 6.
Also note that you need to move the 01 definitions to position 8 as shown below
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+-
       FD DATOS.                                        
       01 REG-DAT.                                      
           05  ID-LB           PIC 9(10).               
           05  TITULO          PIC X(16).               
           05  GEN-1           PIC X(8).                
           05  GEN-2           PIC X(11).               
           05  STOCK           PIC 99.                  
           05  FILLER          PIC X(33).               
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                         
       01  FIN                 PIC X VALUE 'N'.         


Doesn't work what you suggest, still shows the same error

@Juan: Then you have more coding changes to make.

like what?? I accept suggestions @GilbertLeBlanc

Juan, You need to get hold of manual of the compiler that you are using and look up the syntax. As mentioned earlier you are using really old compiler and most of us do NOT even use that compiler.

Kolusu and other posters. Could you please make it clear that you are using the Hercules mainframe emulator. The legally available software for this emulator is over twenty years out of date.
